# Conditional aggregation with JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.4. I have a table containing medications, as follows:

```
bnf_code                     │ character varying(15)  │ not null
pills_per_day                │ double precision       │
```

For example, this table might contain a medication with code of `04030201`, with a recommended pills per day of 4, and one with code `04030202` and recommended pills per day of 2.

And I also have a table containing numbers of prescriptions, with a foreign key to the table above:

```
 code              │ character varying(15)   │ not null
 num_pills         │ double precision        │ not null
 processing_date   │ date                    │ not null
 practice_id       │ character varying(6)    │ not null
Foreign-key constraints:
    FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES medications(bnf_code) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Now I need to work out how many daily doses were prescribed for all codes starting `0403`. The daily dose is defined as the number of pills actually prescribed, divided by the recommended pills per day.

I know how to do this for the two particular codes above:

```
SELECT  (SUM(num_pills) FILTER (WHERE code='04030201') / 4) +
        (SUM(num_pills) FILTER (WHERE code='04030202') / 2)
FROM    prescriptions
```

But that's because I can hard-code in the pills per day field.

Can I extend this to divide by the appropriate `pills_per_day` for all codes starting `0403`? There might be several hundred, but I'd prefer to use a single SQL query if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what are you looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(p.num_pills/r.pills_per_day)
FROM prescriptions p INNER join recommendations r 
    ON p.code = r.bnf_code
WHERE p.code Like '0403%'
```

I am assuming that `num_pills` is the number of pills prescribed and `pills_per_day` is the number of pills recommended.

Comment: I can't believe it's that simple! Thanks so much :)